# bin/*.dll locked when deploying website after app_offline.htm copied and active (shadow copy off)

Tags: deployment, app-offline.htm, shadow-copy

I am running into an issue deploying a website. Shadow copy is turned off after previous deployment issues with it and deploying the site.

Specifically at deploy time I find that even after copying `app_offline.htm` and verifying that the site/application is offline, the files in `bin/*.dll` are often locked.

With shadow copy off I would still expect the locks on the dll's to be free'd when the `appdomain` is unloaded on `app_offline.htm` appearance.

I have tried deploying a temporary `web.config` found on `Stack Overflow` which aims to prevent changes (to `bin/`) being picked up immediately just before I try to delete the contents of `bin/`
I even pause for `10s` after copying the new `web.config`.

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime waitChangeNotification="300"
       maxWaitChangeNotification="300"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"  />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I have confirmed with the handles util that my application pool (`w3wp.exe` process) is the holder of a lock on the dlls so am assuming this is the reason why I cannot delete/overwrite the files. If i manually recycle the app pool it frees it up and I am able to deploy just fine. Unfortunately as part of the deploy process copying the app_offline and changing the web.config are possible but performing `IIS` appcmd recycles are not (for permissions/group policy reasons) so I really need to be able to free up this lock with just `app_offline.htm` and the web.config.

Turning shadow copy back on does 'solve' this particular issue but if a lock is still held on the dll. However I wonder / and concerned if I am just postponing the problem. Unless the lock on the old dll is free'd when the `appdomain` is loaded again?

When copying the `app_offline.htm` the `w3wp` process id doesn't change like it does with a hard recycle but I assume it is unloading the `appdomain` which should free the `bin/ files` it has locked.

Another interesting point is that this only appears to happen on our production servers, I cannot recreate it locally or on our dev/staging sites. I don't believe there is any config difference with the `app_pools` or `IIS` config but could this possible cause this behavior.

Also to clarify `shadowCopyBinAssemblies` has been set to false for over 3 years without this problem happening (same deploy process) so I really feel like something that happened recently caused this, but I have no idea what.

Thanks for any ideas on how to solve this or even what might be causing it.

(I believe the server is `IIS7` or `7.5`)

Comment: This is an old question, but were you able to resolve this? We are having a very similar issue. If so, you should post the solution as an answer here. Thanks!

Comment: Any ideas, we have same problem, can you share solution? Thanks.

Comment: I am also experiencing this issue.

Answer (score -2):

I am running into a similar issue where a DLL is locked by IIS even with the presence of app_offline.htm.
Restarting the pool solves the issue but it is manual. Looking for an automated way. In my case the DLL is PDFium.dll  it is likely an unmanaged dll

Comment: This does not really propose an answer to the question. You can propose your own question if you have an extension to ask. But the answer section is not a place for this.